# Is Orchard contentManager `List()` identical to Linq Tolist()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

The question is, when I call `ToList()` in a `Linq` (to Sql) query it fetches all the records from db and brings them into memory.and I wonder if `List()` method of orchard ContentManager has same effect ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `List()` returns:

```
_query.Slice(0, 0).AsPart<T>()
```

`Slice(0, 0)` returns the whole result set as a read-only collection, and has the effect of executing the query and bringing the results into memory. `AsPart<T>()` presents the list of content items as a list of parts of type `T`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It absolutely does provide the answer. It was asked whether `List()` had the same effect as Linq's `ToList()` and the answer is yes. It was also accepted as the answer. You assumed wrongly that my answer was a critique or a request for clarification, where it was neither. You should retract your comment and your downvote.

Comment: first of all the comment was generated automatically from a review ("Low Quality Posts" I suppose) and more important I didn't downvote your answer, I can see the vote count and you have +1/-1 and the downvote is not mine, if you want proof of this ask a moderator on Meta or I can downvote it right now, as you prefer

Comment: mmm, apologies for making the bad assumption that you did the downvote. I'm not convinced by the auto-reply justification however. No big deal, I'm just trying to better understand when I get a downvote so I can provide better answers in the future. Feel free to downvote my answer if you have good reason to think it's wrong or incomplete.

Comment: this answer can be correct (I don't know Orchard, I don't downvote on something that I don't know) but sure it's a low quality one, and I will decline it again if it appears in the review queue. You wrote the dots because there is a minimum number of chars, an answer like "Yes, the two methods are the same because one is a wrapper of the other" or "Yes because they implement the same logic for returning the result" probably would not be flagged in the first place, I just did a review, I didn't judge your answer.

Comment: Now that's actionable. Edited.